# Need help understanding proof about connected sets.

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

I am struggling with the very last line of this proof:

[image]

I mean, where does he get the existence of $z_1$ from?, and all the info about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z \not \in \overline{B}$ then there is an open neighbourhood of $z$ disjoint from $B$, $z_1$ is then some element of this nbd, larger than $z$ and smaller than $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much!, but we must also have that $z_1$ is not in A, how do you get that?

Comment: $z$ is the sup of $A \cap [x,y]$ so $z_1$ cant be in $A$.

Comment: Thnank you for your help!